# Sparse Matrix/ Inner Matrix Dimension

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

Well, Trying to do something with search engines.

I have generated a matrix (term-document) from a collection of 5 documents. The output is:

docs= **(5,1)       1.0000
      (1,2)       0.7071
      (3,2)       0.7071
      (1,3)       0.7071
      (5,3)       0.7071
      (3,4)       1.0000
      (4,5)       1.0000**

Also, I have generated a query matrix from user query.

q=  **(1,1)        1
   (2,1)        1**

I'm trying to find similarity of the document set with the user's query applying Vector space modelling. Here goes the code:

```
% docs is a sprase matrix presenting a number of document.
sc=zeros(1, n); doc_inds=zeros(1, n);

% q is the user query. 
sc=q'*docs;

%sort documents according to their
similarity coefficient with the query
[sc, doc_inds]=sort(sc);
sc=sc(end:-1:1);doc_inds=doc_inds(end:-1:1);
```

The line `sc=q'*docs;` always produces error saying: **??? Inner matrix dimensions must** . **agree.**

Can anyone help me getting an idea to deal with it ? Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the data in your example, `docs` is 5x5 and `q` is 2x1. The matrix multiplication `q'*docs` is attempting to multiply a 1x2 matrix with a 5x5 matrix. Matrix multiplication requires that the second dimension of the first matrix agrees with the first dimension of the second matrix, thus the error you are getting.

Why are you defining `sc` at the line `sc=zeros(1, n);` and then overwriting it with this matrix multiplication?

Comment: I understand the matrix dimension requirement. However, I can't control the dimension and they are going to be different normally. The Formula demands them to be multiplied.@b3, isn't declaring size of variable a good practice ?

Comment: @Tinglin - Without knowing more about the algorithm it's really difficult to comment. It seems you need to check your assumptions. Either the query and docs matrices have to be multiplicable or the algorithm must be changed.

Comment: I'll go through the assumptions now. Thanks for pointing it out. If I can't find anything, I'll post it for you and other's insight.

Comment: Thanks heaps. I found the problem. It is when I generate the query matrix, I used a wrong variable. That changed the dimension. It's working fine now. I understood, it had nothing to do with being sparse matrix. It is just the basic rule of matrix multiplication.